# How to document object's contract

Tags: javascript, oop, interface, contract

I'm trying to find a good way to document expected "interface" or "contract" of an object in JavaScript, e.g. which methods would be called, which properties are expected to be present and so on. I want it to be as close to code as possible (e.g. not in external documentation files).

Let's say I'm trying to design UI controls library in JavaScript. I would like to process a set of controls in a polymorphic way, e.g. call `control.loadDataFromServer()` regardless of whether it's a text field or dropdown or whatever. But some behavior may not be present in all types of controls, for example for editable controls I would call `control.validate()` or `control.getValue()` which won't happen for static text labels and such.

My main main goal is so a new developer trying to implement new control or modify the existing one can immediately understand what is possible to implement without having to sift through all the calling code.

In a statically typed language like C# or Java, I would have used interfaces like `IControl` and `IEditableControl`. Now, I know JavaScript is duck typed, but I do want to give some hints to further developers. I could provided dummy implementation in a control's prototype, but that solution seems dirty to me. What are my options?

Comment: Are you looking for a format to comment out your code (and possibly generate documentation from it), like JsDoc? Or are you looking for a way to write your code to be more self-documenting?

Comment: Maybe have a look at leaflet: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html. They use lots of interfaces, at least in the documentation. Either way, it's probably worth to have a look at their source code.

Comment: @Tibos, I would like self-documenting code more, but I don't like to pollute my prototypes with dummy methods just for that purpose. As for JSDoc, I don't see how I can document different optional "aspects" of the object. BTW I don't need to generate external documentation files at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to use something along the lines of this quacksLike solution http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/39/.

For each logical "interface" I create an object which lists members along with very basic type indication using JS prototypes (String, Number, Function etc.). This interface objects are very easy to document with JSDoc (also to add missing information about method parameters).

When working with target objects, I check if object intends to support the "interface" and if so, I go ahead and call methods. It's not as safe as static typing, but good enough for me.

```
var interfaces = {
     ...
     validatable: {
         validate: Function,
         isValid: Boolean,
         getValidationMessages: Function
     }
     ....
}

...
if (typing.checkSupport(control, interfaces.validatable)) {
    control.validate();  
    if (!control.isValid) {
      ....
    }
}
```